# How to get this piece of code into loop, so that it asks a user input each time until the result is "kill"?

Tags: java, loops

I was practicing this piece of code from the book 'Head First Java' and I'm quite confused on the positioning of the loop here.The code is for creating a kind of game that has a random dotcom word(ex: abc.com) occupying some array elements. here I gave that dotcom word the positions from 3 to 5 in the array, and the user tries guessing the position.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RunTheGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MainGameClass sampleObj= new MainGameClass();
        int[] location = {3,4,5};
        sampleObj.setdotcomLocationCells(location);


        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your guess");
        int userGuess=input.nextInt();

        String answer = sampleObj.checkForDotcom(userGuess);
        System.out.println(answer);

    }
}
```

---

```
package simpleDotComGame;

public class MainGameClass {
    int[] DotcomLocationCells;
    int numOfHits=0;

    public void setdotcomLocationCells(int[] location) {
        DotcomLocationCells= location;
    }

    public String checkForDotcom(int userGuess) {
        String result="miss";
        for(int cell:DotcomLocationCells) {
            if(cell == userGuess) {
                result ="hit";
                numOfHits++;
                break;
            }
        } // end for loop

        if(numOfHits == DotcomLocationCells.length) {
            result = "kill";            
            System.out.println("The number of tries= "+numOfHits);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allowed to declare the variable before initializing it:

```
String answer;
do {
  answer = sampleObj.checkForDotcom(userGuess);
  System.out.println(answer);
} while (!answer.equals("kill");
```

Also beware of the semantics of `Scanner.nextInt()`: if it can't parse the input as an int (for example, it contains letters), it will throw an exception, but won't jump over the invalid input. You'll have to use `Scanner.nextLine()` to force-jump over it, otherwise you'll get an infinite loop.

Comment: ohh well! this didn't strike me! Appreciate the quick response! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
do {
        <insert code where answer result is created>
} while (!answer.equals("kill"))
```

**upd.:** but you must override the equals method for correct use, because if you see how method declared in Object.class you find

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
```

Comment: That's not how you check for string equality in Java.

Comment: It would nevertheless work because the literal `"kill"` is assigned to the variable.

Comment: Actually no Markro, because the "kill" == answer is not the same has the result="kill"; these are diferent objects there's not static final variable to define a unique object

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I know it might work but people just beginning Java do not understand the concept of String Pool and should be advised to use `equals()` IMHO.

Comment: @deceiver You are simply wrong (string literals are interned in the global String Constant pool). If you contest that, then try to write a program which disproves me.

Comment: He's not wrong. Though it's not best practice. "String" == "String" but "String" != new String("String")

Comment: @Sam That's a _different_ piece of code. You are moving the goalposts to suit your conclusions.

Comment: @Markro you're right I made a small example and it works. But none the less she should always use the equals, don't put bad habits in newcomers :)

Comment: @AbdulFatir You are absolutely correct that beginners should be warned about the tricky semantics. However claiming that `s1 == s2` is a nonsense construct which should never be used is going too far in the opposite direction.

Comment: okay, I understood how @MarkoTopolnik is trying to make me use the best practices, and I'll keep that in mind. I just tried this solution but I'm afraid I can't use "answer" in the while condition when I'm declaring it inside do loop.

Comment: @Abdul Fatir is "equals" methos is not same as "==" how to explain to beginner user why in Object.class method equals declared as public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);

Answer (score 0):

Rachna, the loop will be positioned, around the following code:

```
Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your guess");
int userGuess=input.nextInt();

String answer=sampleObj.checkForDotcom(userGuess);
System.out.println(answer);
//For string you must use the equals
if ("kill".equals(answer)){
   break;
}
```

The reason why is that the kill command must be evaluated inside the loop to break it, and the input to continuously ask the user input until he hits all targets.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how the loop should be positioned.

```
String answer = "";
do{
    System.out.println("Enter your guess");
    int userGuess=input.nextInt();

    answer=sampleObj.checkForDotcom(userGuess);
    System.out.println(answer);
}
while(!answer.equals("kill"));
```

**NOTE**: Never Check for String equality using `==` in Java unless you know what you're doing (also read as, unless you know the concept of String Constant Pool).

Comment: I'm a starter at this and really didn't know that we could use 'answer' that way, like we use for objects. Also, since the String answer was declared inside the do loop, I'm facing error for that variable in the while condition.

Comment: @RachnaBalani `answer` is actually an object of class `String`, so yes, you can use it as an object and call methods on it. Please mark as the answer if this helped. :)

Comment: This code doesn't compile for the reason OP explained.

Comment: @Abdul All right :) But the problem still persists. I'm not able to understand what exactly to place under the loop since the `String answer=sampleObj.checkForDotcom(userGuess);` is declared inside the do loop and I can't use it outside the loop in the while condition.

Comment: declare a variable outside of the loop as the @Abdul Fatir wrote in his example
p.s. code is very correct in his example